# SQL Transaction was deadlocked

Tags: sql-server, exception, stored-procedures, triggers

Sometimes I get this kind of exception on not very busy SQL server:

```
Transaction (Process ID 57) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
Line number: 1
Error Number: 1205
Procedure: 
Server name: P01
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error State: 47
```

I'm not able to reproduce it. I tried to run several queries from different clients at the same time, but it didn't show up.
What is the best way to handle this kind of issue when it happens inside procedure or inside trigger? I mean, how to rerun the transaction?

How to do it when exception occurs inside procedure called from the trigger, which was called by the insert made by some procedure (that is: procedure01 -> insert -> trigger -> procedure02 !)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would suggest that you come at the problem from two perspectives.

1. [Trap or Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177453.aspx) *Deadlock Errors* so that you can re-run the transaction that is chosen as the *Deadlock Victim* by the SQL Server database engine.
2. Find out what is causing your *Deadlock Events.* 
   You can do this in one of two ways, either run a *SQL Server Profiler Trace* to catch and record the Deadlock Event or you can enable some [SQL Server *Trace Flags*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx) that will record the details of the Deadlock Event to the SQL Server Error Log.

In the **vast majority** of cases, you can identify the cause of your Deadlock Events and remedy the situation through either a structural change in the database schema or a logical change to the code involved/responsible for the Deadlock Event.

For further reading take a look at:

- [How to track down Deadlocks Using SQL Server Profiler](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/)
- [Minimizing Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191242.aspx)
- [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx)

I hope I've answered your question but do let me know if I can help you further in any way.

Comment: ***what is causing your Deadlock Events?*** not performance decrease

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if there was any hint on what generally causes the errors. Is it in my application code? SQL procedure? Bug in MSSQL?

Answer (score 5):

Set up a server-side SQL trace which captures deadlock graph events so you can look at the .trc file with SQL Profiler. This way you can have something in place to be able to troubleshoot any deadlock. I have provided the code below. You will have to change the file path as appropriate. It would be a good idea to configure this script to execute on SQL server startup.

FYI - A lot of different things can cause a deadlock, one of them being missing indexes.

```
declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int
declare @maxfilesize bigint
set @maxfilesize = 10 
declare @dtName nvarchar(50)
select @dtName=(N'I:\Trace_Logs\DeadLockTrace'+ convert(nvarchar(8),getdate(),112))


-- Please replace the text InsertFileNameHere, with an appropriate
-- filename prefixed by a path, e.g., c:\MyFolder\MyTrace. The .trc extension
-- will be appended to the filename automatically. If you are writing from
-- remote server to local drive, please use UNC path and make sure server has
-- write access to your network share

exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 2, @dtName, @maxfilesize, NULL ,365

if (@rc != 0) goto error

-- Client side File and Table cannot be scripted

-- Set the events
declare @on bit
set @on = 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 4, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 60, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 148, 41, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 7, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 15, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 55, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 8, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 32, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 56, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 9, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 25, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 41, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 49, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 57, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 10, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 58, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 3, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 4, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 52, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 60, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 6, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 25, 22, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 55, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 32, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 56, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 64, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 21, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 25, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 41, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 49, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 57, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 2, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 14, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 22, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 26, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 58, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 3, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 51, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 4, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 52, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 59, 60, @on

-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

-- Set the trace status to start
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1

-- display trace id for future references
select TraceID=@TraceID
goto finish

error: 
select ErrorCode=@rc

finish: 
go
```

Comment: In my case it was missing index that caused deadlock.

Comment: how do i use an UNC path?

Answer (score 2):

I solved like problem using ReadCommited isolation level.

Answer (score 0):

I am resolved this error by:

1. Restart SQL Server
2. Run Query:

   USE [master]
   ALTER DATABASE name_database
   SET MULTI_USER
   WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

Goodluck!