# Parallel.ForEach used with NHibernate resulting in SQL Server locks

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, .net-4.0, nhibernate-4

Firstly, I am not much of an expert in multi-threading and parallel programming.

I am trying to optimize the performance of a legacy application (`.Net 4`, `NHibernate 2.1`).

**So far, upgrading `NHibernate` is not a priority, but is in the pipeline.

Over time, performance has become a nightmare with the growth of data. One item I have seen is a `Parallel.ForEach` statement that calls a method that fetches and updates a complex entity(with multiple relationships - propeties & collections).

The piece of code has the following **form** (simplified for clarity):

```
void SomeMethod(ICollection<TheClass> itemsToProcess)
{
   Parallel.ForEach(itemsToProcess, item => ProcessItem(item);
}

TheClass ProcessItem(TheClass i)
{
   var temp = NHibernateRepository.SomeFetchMethod(i);
   var result = NHibernateRepository.Update(temp);
   return result;
}
```

SQL Server intermittently reports database lock errors with the following error:

`Transaction (Process ID 20) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction`

I suspect it is due to some race condition happening leading up to a deadlock, even if `ISessions` are separate.

The `ICollection<TheClass>` can have up to 1000 items and each with properties and sub-collections that are processed, generating many `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements (confirmed using 'NHibernate Profiler')

**Is there a better way to handle this in a parallel way, or shall I refactor the code to a traditional loop?**

I do know that I can alternatively implement my code using:

1. A `foreach` loop in the same `ISession` context
2. With a Stateless Session
3. With `Environment.BatchSize` set to a reasonable value

OR

1. Using SQL BulkCopy

I have also read quite a bit of good info about SQL Server deadlocks and  `Parallel.ForEach` being an easy pitfall:

1. [SQL Transaction was deadlocked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5391427/919426)
2. [Using SQL Bulk Copy as an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636297/919426)
3. [Potential Pitfalls in Data and Task Parallelism](http://Potential%20Pitfalls%20in%20Data%20and%20Task%20Parallelism)
4. [Multi threading C# application with SQL Server database calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10035988/919426)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complicated topic. There's one strategy that is guaranteed to be safe and *probably* will result in a speedup:

Retry in case of deadlock.

Since a deadlock rolls back the transaction you can safely retry the entire transaction. If the deadlock rate is low the parallelism speedup will be high.

The nice thing about retry is that you can make a simple code change in a central place.

Since it's not apparent from the code posted: Make sure, that threads do not share the session or entities. Neither of them are thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is complicated indeed and possible solutions are mult-pronged. Will try your Retry strategy. The other complexity that adds more spanners to the works is the multiple `SELECTS` and `UPDATES` that happen for some entities due to the `NHibernate` key generation strategy. The threads do net share the same session, as I mentioned

Comment: The hilo key generation should happen in a separate transaction if NHibernate does it correctly. There should be no deadlocks involving that. You can check that using SQL Profiler.